# UV Hand Painted problem with colors

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, color

As you can see from the image, the mushroom should be red but it appears wine and the white circles appears blue. I'm using a Diffuse Color on Texture Paint Slot

Edit: Answer below

[image]

Comment: Did you change blending mode in the [influence settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/properties/influence/introduction.html#introduction)?

Comment: I found out what it was, i was using mask without knowing

Comment: If you found answer to your question answer it yourself, make sure to show some details like screenshots of settings you changed to make it working.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Unchecked the Mask option and it got normal

[image]